# Variable, defined insde for loop of window.onload function, gets global scope at window level

Tags: javascript, loops, global-variables, onload

I have a function set to *window.onload* event. Inside that function I have a *for loop*, that defines variable *unit* on every iteration as a new object of type *GAME.Unit*. As a result of this, I have a variable *unit* in *window* scope, holding last created object! I always thought, variables inside loop are loop-oriented. I double-checked and there are no other declarations on *unit* variable anywhere in my code. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your `console.log()` statement is **inside the function**! You aren't looking in the global scope!

Comment: Of course it inside function, but it is not inside loop, where variable created. If I put it anywhere else in my code, variable still there.

Comment: The `var` statement declares a variable which is closure scoped. (That means the variable is accessible in the whole function body.) If you want the variable to be accessible only in the loop, you need to use `let` or `const`.

Also your `console.log` is inside the function, so it's not really in the window scope.

Comment: @Razem — There are no closures here. You only get a closure if a function has a variable scoped to it, another function is declared inside that function, the inner function uses the variable from the outer function, and the life of the inner function extends past the life of the outer function. Don't confuse closures with functions.

Comment: What a wonder, never knew that variable inside loops will behave like this...

Comment: @Quentin - Yeah, right. Not a closure. Just one function scope. But I hope you get the point. If you write a code like this:

    function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      }
      
      console.log(i);
    }
    
Then it's completely valid and it will output 10. However if you write a code like this:

    function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      }
      
      console.log(i);
    }
   
It will throw an error.

Comment: @Razem — Reading from an undeclared variable will always throw a reference error. Strict mode stops you implicitly creating a global by *writing* to an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either **the enclosing function** or, for variables declared outside any function, global.

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

`var` scopes a variable to the function, not the loop.

To scope a variable to a block, use `let`.